# Android cancel notification with key throws security exception

Tags: android

Noticed a few stack traces with a SecurityException thrown when I run `cancelNotification(String key)` in a `NotificationListenerService`. Isn't this supposed not to happen?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.cancelNotificationsFromListener(INotificationManager.java:985)
```

Comment: Check the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String)) to see if you have handled all cases.

Comment: @dustblue the only possible "case" unhandled could be if the onListenerConnected() has not been fired at that point.